# UWP: how to setup namespace for templated control

Tags: templates, uwp, uno-platform

I want to create a templated control and, for my "shared" project, have used the Add New Item dialog to create a default templated control. This builds but, of course, it is not yet used in my project.

How do I reference it in my main page ? I see plenty of examples but none, that I can find, explain how to setup the namespaces.

It created Themes\Generic.xaml and TitlebarTemplate.cs (the latter being the name I chose for my template).

Here's my Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UnoTest.Shared">

    <Style TargetType="local:TitlebarTemplate" >
      ...
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And, here's a very condensed main page:

```
<Page
  x:Class="UnoTest.ListPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:UnoTest"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  >

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"  />
      ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    ... put template here ...
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

What namespace to I need to add to reference the template ? And, please include the syntax for actually referencing it.

I'm doing this for the Uno platform, but I think the syntax is the same as for UWP.

EDIT

I put this in my page:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But I still can't find a way to reference `TitlebarTemplate`.

Comment: It is indeed necessary to explicitly reference the `Generic.xaml` dictionary in Uno as you did (although it is done automatically in UWP). However, after that, it should behave correctly. Can you confirm the current code you have works properly in UWP?

Answer (score 1):

using:

```
xmlns:dt="UnoTest.Themes"
```

Should be sufficient. This would be your `ProjectName`.`AnyDirectoryYouHave`

Any `xaml` file you add to the Shared library will take the global namespace (without the Shared).

Notes:

We usually keep all the Styles related files in the UWP head, grouping the Styles in files by Controls.

[image]

And then merging all these Styles into the Application Dictionary found at the `App.xaml` file.

[image]

By doing this you will be able to access your `Template` and any other `Style` from any Page in the application without the need of importing it.

This means you could use your General Resource Dictionary and merge it as part of the Application Dictionary in your App and then just use it from your Page.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Tried that: I added xmlns:themes="UnoTest.Themes" to my main page xaml. Then, below I try to reference the template but nothing seems to work. I tried <themes:TitlebarTemplate />, <themes:Generic.TitlebarTemplate /> and <themes:Generic /> All are unrecognized.

Comment: I see better now.. A couple of things, a `ResourceDictionary` living into in own file needs to be merged into the Application Dictionary or the Page Dictionary so that you can use it. The Styles you define will have a `Key` that you will later use to reference it and apply it to a Control by using something like  `Style={StaticResource YourKey}`  This is the way you should get your Template working in a page. Will update the answer to add more information for you. @PeriHartman

Comment: Another question: What is `TitlebarTemplate` ? Could you update the question with the content of this file, or at least the global definition?

Comment: `TitlebarTemplate` is the name I gave my templated control, in Generic.xaml.

Comment: Abut merging the dictionary: do you mean put it in App.xaml ? I want to share the control among pages, so I don't think I should be putting it in one of my page dictionaries, right ?

Comment: Please see EDIT in OP.